# Find Where $f(z)=x^2+iy^2$ Differentiable And Analytic

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Let $f(z)=x^2+iy^2$ find where it is differentiable and where it is analytic in $\mathbb{C}$

For a function to be differentiable at a point it should fulfil C-R equations, we have

$u(x,y)=x^2$ and $v(x,y)=y^2$

So $u_x=2x=2y=v_y$ and $u_y=0=0-v_x$

So the function is differentiable iff $2x=2y\iff x=y$

So the function is differentiable on the straight line $y=x$

So $f(z)$ is not analytic? as it is only differentiable on a straight line and not in areas are a point? on the other hand the function seems to have no problematic points (singularities) so it is analytic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on the definition of analytic function that you use. But if it is the usual one (which implies that if $f$ is analytic at a point $z$ then it is analytic in all points of a neighborhood of $z$) than $f$ is analytic nowhere.

Comment: Can we add that because $u_{xx}+u_{vv}\neq 0$ and $v_{xx}+v_{yy}\neq 0$ so the function is analytic nowhere?

Comment: No. Why is that?

Comment: Because a function is analytic iff $u,v$ are harmonic conjugate

Comment: Note that it was possible that $f$ was not analytic globally while, at the same time, it was analytic on some open subset of $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Is there an example, in the question I am asked to find where it is analytic at $\mathbb{C}$ so it can be just "analytic on some open subset of $\mathbb{C}$" but not globally

Comment: Take$$f(z)=\begin{cases}\operatorname{Re}^2z&\text{ if }\operatorname{Re}z>0\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$Then the largest open subset of $\mathbb C$ on which $f$ is analytic is $\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,|\,\operatorname{Re}z<0\}$.

Answer (score 2):

If you want differentiable as a function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ ($f(x,y)=(x^2,y^2)$). This function is differentiable at all points, since its components have continuous partial derivatives everywhere.

The Cauchy-Riemann equations give you where it is complex-differentiable. You have found that complex derivative exist at every point of the line $y=x$.

To be analytic at a point it has to have complex derivative at a neighborhood of the point. This is because being analytic means that the function is equal to a convergent power series with a radius of convergence larger than $0$. In the interior of the disc of convergence, the sum of a power series has complex derivatives. Take into account that while this is a simple result, it is something that still requires a proof. As such, it is good to make it explicit in the proof since what you get from Cauchy-Riemann is existence of complex derivatives, a related, but different condition.

This function doesn't have complex derivative on any open set since the line $y=x$ has an empty interior. Therefore, it is not analytic anywhere.